# Sort data in an array before displaying in a table in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, html-table

I am trying to make a PHP page to display sorted data in a table. There are text files sent to us which contains raw/mixed text info. Through string concatenation I can find a way to retrieve the records out of that raw file but my problem is how to display the data in a table already sorted by timestamp/date. If I use MySQL I could move the collected data into a MySQL table then retrieve it sorted but my goal is to do all these without going through different websites or adding different tools. I was thinking maybe there is a way to sort your array?

Example raw data contents from a text file:

> "Name": "Jay Parks", "Status": "Single", "Date": "1/12/2013", "Name": "Sandy Rock", "Status": "Married", "Date": "1/24/2013"

The content is actually big but that is just an example. I can find a way to store each data to an array in PHP like `VariableA(1)="Jay Parks"` and `VariableB(1)="Single"` or something like that. I can go ahead and display that in a table but it wouldn't be sorted by date. So is there a way to sort a table contents in PHP without having to use jQuery or MySQL or anything like that? I have been researching for weeks now but couldn't even get anywhere close to solving this.

Comment: You can of course sort arrays. Get all the values into a 2d array, and use [array_multisort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php)

Comment: Thank you, I would put a vote on your answer but I can't seem to find the star or vote button beside your comment. But you are awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout PHP sorting functions:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php